# Why would a senior PI need to take a part-time job at another university?

Tags: career-path, professorship, part-time, joint-appointment

A senior professor works at one university, has his own lab and research group(s). Recently, he took another part-time job at a better university. So why do professors need to take part-time jobs? Is it because his main university started to pay half salary or is it because he needs extra funding to work together at another university? Or just because he lacks funding and seeking opportunity somewhere else?

Does this professor reserve to right to ask the new faculty to employ or joint pay his research fellow? Or this is more usual that he needs to pay his staff with his own funding.

Comment: Are you a student or a professor at the university?

Comment: I am not a professor

Comment: thank you for reviewing my question, i ask here as know few about the academic world, do you know the answer? and if this is a good question?

Comment: Most people take additional work to get more money, or get something else out of the deal that is worth money. That being said, I feel in poor taste to inquire about this professor's specific scenario.

Comment: the question may sounds stupid, but it is necessary for us students also to know the academic system. really looking forward to know the answer

Comment: Maybe you could just ask that professor yourself...  Might be enlightening.

Comment: Perhaps the prof is doing some friendly department a favor, and covering some dire circumstance.  Really, could be anything.

Comment: I remember in the 2nd meeting of one of my classes, the professor announced he had been diagnosed with cancer and was taking a medical leave.  The university hired other professors to take over his responsibilities.  It could be as simple as that.

Comment: I am a faculty member at a third-tier university.  If a first-tier university in the same city offered me a part-time job and I could fit in the time required, I'd take it so fast it would make your head spin.

Comment: Maybe he has multiple ex-wives?

Answer (score 14):

> A senior professor works at one university, has his own lab and research group(s). Recently, he took another part-time job at a better university. So why do professors need to take part-time jobs?

Of course there's no way to say for sure based on so little information, but I wouldn't assume it has anything to do with finances, actually. The most likely explanation is that he wanted to be associated in some way with the more prestigious university. Maybe just because it sounds impressive (either to society at large or on papers/grants), maybe because he hopes to move there fully in the future, maybe because the association might help him attract strong students or postdocs, maybe because he is collaborating with someone there or managing a joint grant, etc.

> Does this professor reserve to right to ask the new faculty to employ or joint pay his research fellow?

There's no way of answering this without much more information. Some people have affiliations with other universities that consist of just a title (with no salary or research funding at all), others genuinely have part-time jobs, and some have negotiated deals involving all sorts of things. In general I wouldn't assume there's any agreement to provide joint funding for research fellows, but there might be.